# struggling to locate element to target on hover of another

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help me understand how jQuery find/closest works. I want to add a class to an element on hover of another - markup example is below. I cant seem to get it to work whatever I try...!

I want on hover of "inner" div to add "chevronAnimedRight" class to the "span.chevron" element.

Why does the below not work?

Please note I need this to be specific to this particular "nectar-post-grid-item" div as there are many on the page...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nectar-post-grid-item .inner').hover(
    function() {
      $('h3.post-heading a span.chevron', this).toggleClass('chevronAnimedRight');



    });
});
```

```css
.nectar-post-grid-item {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

span.chevron {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

span.chevron.chevronAnimedRight {
  background: orange;
}

h3.post-heading a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item animated-in" data-has-img="true">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item-bg"></div>
    <div class="bg-overlay" data-opacity="0.3" data-hover-opacity="0.4"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="nectar-post-grid-link" href="#" aria-label="Project 10"></a>
      <div class="item-main">
        <p id="foliotItemDescription">Nulla facilisi vestibulum aliquam turpi.</p>
        <p class="location" id="foliotItemLocation">Location</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="#"><span>Project 10</span><span class="chevron"><img src="chevron-right.svg" alt="Read more" title="Read more"></span>
</a></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: the element you are trying to find is a sibling of inner, not a child.

Comment: OK thanks - any chance of a demo of it so I can look at the correct code?

Comment: siblings() or next()

Comment: `$(this).next('h3.post-heading').find('a span.chevron').toggleClass('chevronAnimedRight');`

Comment: @j08691 thanks - thats perfect

Comment: so its a combo of next and find ok - will learn for next time!